# Multiple ROI in video stream of webcam

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

[image]I am looking to process a video stream from webcam. I am using opencv to capture and display the video.
My goal is to segment the video display window into 3 rectangles with specified width and height. When an object is detected in the rectangle then it should output left center or right. I have managed to calculated the center coordinate of the object and drawn the rectangles on the video stream display window. Based on the coordinate where it falls in one of the rectangles, then  the output will be left, center or right.

My question is how do i make the output when the coordinate falls within one of the box. I assumed using if center_coord in box then output but it does not work.

```
 import cv2
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
import numpy as np
import time
from collections import namedtuple
options = {
    'model': 'cfg/yolov2.cfg',
    'load': 'bin/yolov2.weights',
    'threshold': 0.8,
    'gpu': 0.8
}


tfnet = TFNet(options)
colors = [tuple(255 * np.random.rand(3)) for _ in range(10)]

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
center_coord = namedtuple("center_coord", ['x', 'y'])

while True:
    stime = time.time()
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    box = cv2.rectangle(frame, (1, 0), (426, 720), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    box2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (426, 0), (852, 720), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    box3 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (852, 0), (1279, 720), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    if ret:
        results = tfnet.return_predict(frame)
        for color, result in zip(colors, results):
            tl = (result['topleft']['x'], result['topleft']['y'])
            br = (result['bottomright']['x'], result['bottomright']['y'])
            center_x = ((tl[0] + br[0])/2)
            center_y = ((tl[1] + br[1])/2)
            center_box = center_coord(center_x, center_y)
            print(center_box)
            label = result['label']
            confidence = result['confidence']
            text = '{}: {:.0f}%'.format(label, confidence * 100)
            frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, tl, br, color, 5)
            frame = cv2.putText(frame, text, tl, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        print('FPS {:.1f}'.format(1 / (time.time() - stime)))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it by using simple if else statement ranging the x coordinate based on width of my resolution window.

```
def box_tracking(self, center):
    self.center = center
    while True:
        if 0 <= center <= 426:
            center = -1
            print("Object on left")
        elif 426 < center <= 852:
            center = 0
            print("Object on center")
        elif 852 < center <= 1280:
            center = 1
            print("Object on right")
        else:
            center = 2
            print("No object detected")
        break
    luggage_arduino.Arduino(center)
```